# Showing a div while page is loading, hiding when its done

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show a `div` with a loading animation over my page while the page loads some XML content. Once its loaded, I want to hide this div.  How can I go about doing this?

Comment: How is the XML content loaded? Is it via AJAX?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/test.xml',
    beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
        // Show the div before sending the request
        $('#load').show();
    },
    complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
        // Hide the div no matter if the call succeeded or not
        $('#load').hide();
    },
    success: function(xml) {
        // if the request succeeds do something with the received XML           
    }
});
```

Comment: Why is this the "best" solution here ? Mine is almost identical and has "0". Not that I care but makes me wonder about the "scoring system" here ?

Answer (score 3):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "your.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#div').fadeIn();
    },
    success: function(xml) {
       // example for parsing xml
       $(xml).find('YOUR_XML_TAG').each(function(){
           // append xml to page HERE
       });
    },
    complete: function() {
       $('#div').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

@cballou  Your code will leave '#div' "up", if $.ajax() has not suceeded for any of numerous possible reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Almost right ;)
Never under-estimate the importance of removing redundant $() calls. So ...

```
//all of this is inside some closure or function
var $blanket = $("#div") ; 
// check if after last call, something has possibly removed your '#div'
// throw if false
ASSERT( $blanket.length === 1 ) ;    
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "your.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        beforeSend: function() {  $blanket.fadeIn();
        },
        success: function(xml) {
           // example for parsing xml
           $(xml).find('YOUR_XML_TAG').each(function(){
               // append xml to page HERE
           });
        },
        complete: function() { $blanket.fadeOut();
        }
    });
```

--DBJ

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) event fired when the page URL changes, to create an overlay div with opacity at 0.5, which will be replaced by the new content when the page is loaded.