# loading for HTML5

Tags: html

I am launching a mobile site and I want it to have a loading icon while loading all the content and images.

Details:
I have several pages. I want when I click on  it will load the pages (to other html page), but I don't want to show the page without fully loaded and I want to show loading animation while it loading all the content. Once, the content is fully loaded. then the loading animation have to hide.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give a more specific question to get more specific (useful answers).

In the meantime here are some (hopefully useful) resources:

http://www.devcurry.com/2009/05/display-progress-bar-while-loading.html

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/display-loading-gif-image-while-loading.html

http://banagale.com/display-a-simple-loading-message-and-animated-loading-gif-using-javascript.htm

http://yensdesign.com/2008/11/how-to-create-a-stylish-loading-bar-as-gmail-in-javascript/

This one may come particularly if it applies to your situation:

[Showing a div while page is loading, hiding when its done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680650/showing-a-div-while-page-is-loading-hiding-when-its-done)

Good luck!

Comment: I see the showing div with while page, but it's an xml call, I am only simple html call, how do you change the code?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a large `<div>` at the beginning of the page, then hide it using Javascript in the `load` event or using an illegal `<style>` block at the end of the `<body>`.

Answer (score 0):

Any number of ways, but you will need javascript.

Comment: Actually, you don't need Javascript.  This is a useless answer.

Comment: One way to do it, how gmail does it, for example is through progressive enhancement. Load the core page elements first, and then using javascript (jQuery), load the heavier elements with a simple ajax get request that only fires when the dom is ready. It will allow the core stuff to load fast and then the other stuff to load after a basic interface is there. The rub is accessibility, what if the user doesn't have js turned on - you should (but don't have to) provide the data for everyone - even if that is a separate html only page. 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: no, read the jquery docs, that is a good start and there are samples there. otherwise you won't learn. Furthermore, an example I write for you may not suit your specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

You are ready when all image assets have been loaded. Define full screen div that covers the whole page. In this div, show e.g. loading spinner animated gif and what ever text you want.

```
 <html>
    <head> .. </head>
    <body>
       <div id="loader"> .. </div>
       <div id="content" style="display:none"> .. </div>
       <script> .. </script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

On your script preload all images. This ensures that they are in cache when they are needed.

```
<script>
var loadc = 0;
function _preload(path) {
   var image = new Image;
   image.src = path;
   image.addEventListener('load', function() {
       loadc++;
       if (loadc == images.count) {
          $("#loader").hide();
          $("#hide").show();
       }
       //  update here progress counter on loading div
   };
}
var images = [ '/image/some.png', '/foo/bar.png' ]
$(document).ready(function() {
     for (var i = 0 ; i < images.length; i++) _preload(images[i]);
});
</script>
```

You need to define in `images` array all assets that you want to be ready when content div is shown, this includes stuff referred from CSS and DOM and possible dynamic DOM. You can use this same method for other assets, like audio and json.